# Extract numerical data from complicated pattern in a plain-text file and produce tabular output

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

This is an SOS question. My professor asked me to obtain output from a long-running simulation code bequeathed to us by a former post-doc (who had explained to me its workings).

I had done a few small-scale trial runs and everything went fine. Then I started the full simulation about a month back and has been running continuously since then. But just a few minutes ago, due to some memory issues, the program crashed before it could write the formatted tabular output to disk.

Luckily, I had enabled terminal echoing of the intermediate results, and had set my scroll-back history to a large value. I managed to salvage partial output by entering scroll-back mode and copying the entire terminal dump into a text file (and also made backup copies of it).

Now, this terminal output is quite verbose (intentionally set so for debug purposes). The following is a snapshot from the salvaged terminal output text file (let us call it `terminal_output.txt`)

```
1 Linear search iteration no. 1 begins: Attempting to blah blah with 1 ...
2 blah blah 
3 blah 
4 blah blah blah
5 lorem ipsum 
.........
........
75 Success with 128 blah ....
76 blah blah
77 blah blah
78 result_flag: 1, exit_reason: 6
79 blah
80 Completed optimal computation with T_init = 25.00 degC & T_sink = 35.00 degC
```

And then this exact pattern repeats. e.g.,

```
81 Linear search iteration no. 2 begins: Attempting to blah blah with 1 ...
82 blah
......
95 Success with 307 blah ....
......
......
100 Completed optimal computation with T_init = 30.00 degC & T_sink = 40.00 degC
```

My requirement is to extract the following information to produce a tabular output like:

```
25  35  128
30  40  307
...........
...........
```

i.e. the 1st & 2nd columns are from the numerical values corresponding to `T_init` and `T_sink` respectively, from those lines begin with `Completed`.  The 3rd column is the numerical value from the line that begins with `Success` (which is always 5 rows before `Completed` if that helps). Any separator between the columns is acceptable-be it spaces, tabs or comma.

I wish to do this natively using standard *nix utilities such as `grep`, `sed` and `awk` or even `vi/vim`. Either piped one-liners strung together or `bash` scripts is fine. If necessary, I am open to using `python`, `perl` or other scripting languages also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially a matter of capturing the parts you want, and discarding the parts you don't. For example using `sed`, you could capture the integer `Success` value and copy it to the hold space (**h**), retrieving and appending it (**G**) to the captured digits of the `Completed` line:

```
sed -nE \
  -e '/Success/ {s/.* ([0-9]+).*/\1/; h;}' \
  -e '/Completed/{G; s/.*T_init = ([0-9]+)\.00 degC & T_sink = ([0-9]+).*\n/\1 \2 /; p;}
' terminal_output.txt
```

Perl provides a somewhat more expressive syntax, which IMHO is more readable:

```
perl -lne '
  our $a = $1 if /Success.*?(\d+)/; print join " ", /(\d+)\.\d+/g, $a if /Completed/
' terminal_output.txt
```

produces the desired output

```
25 35 128
30 40 307
```

Comment: Woohoo...That worked . Thank you very much. Really, using ```perl``` over the venerable ```sed``` and ```awk``` ? Also, for educational purposes, can you please provide an explanation of how your code works?

Comment: Is it because the PCRE engine is more advanced than the others?

Comment: @Krishna it's certainly possible in sed or awk, however perl has some features that make it easier IMHO

Comment: thank you for the explanation and the nice answer. It was a life-saver!

Answer (score 0):

POSIX-compatible `sed`:

```
grep -e 'Success' -e 'Completed' your_file | sed 'N;s/Success with \([[:digit:]]\+\).*T_init = \([^[:space:]]\+\).*T_sink = \([^[:space:]]\+\).*/\2 \3 \1/;s/\.00//g'
```

GNU `sed`: (in which `.` does not match `\n` at least in 4.2.2 on CentOS)

```
grep -e 'Success' -e 'Completed' your_file | sed 'N;s/Success with \([[:digit:]]\+\).*\n.*T_init = \([^[:space:]]\+\).*T_sink = \([^[:space:]]\+\).*/\2 \3 \1/;s/\.00//g'
```

Grabs lines  containing `Success` and `Completed`, then operating on two lines (way more explicitly than necessary) pulls the three fields you care about and orders them into one line.

This only truncates `.00` off of any numbers, leaving any significant fractional component alone (including something like `12.20`, there would still be the single trailing zero).

Caveat where it won't work if some of those `...` lines contain `Completed` or `Success`

Comment: This does not go all the way in extracting the numerical data and producing the tabular output. It does correctly part-way up until identifying only those lines containing the relevant data.

Comment: @Krishna, Aside from what I indicated with the `.00` remaining, is there anything off? My tests do not indicate so. If you indicate that you are looking to truncate that data (didn't want to assume that everything was `.00`), I can update my answer as appropriate. If you want to keep the decimals for non-`.00` data, that is also something we can do

Comment: Yes. All the non-integers are just appended with trailing ```.00```, but your present code does not produce the tabular data I am looking for. Please feel free to edit the answer

Comment: @Krishna, what do you mean "does not produce the tabular data" ? This should output a space-separated line of numbers, per result, same as the perl solution and your example (minus that mine includes decimals)?

Comment: The output is sent to stdout - you can add an `> outfile.txt` on the end of the command to store it

Comment: No....I do not get what you claim. The perl solution produces the desired output... Your solution gives me ```Success with 118 blah blah. \r\n
Completed optimal computation with T_init = 38.00 degC & T_reservoir = 49.00 degC``` ,i.e. leaves me an output with the relevant lines but short of actual columnar data. Yes, even the ```perl``` solution is to ```stdout``` right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76907/discussion-between-krishna-and-cunninghamp3).

Answer (score -1):

A quick `awk` command should get you started:

`awk '$2 ~ /Success/{a=$4;next}; $2 ~ /Completed/{b=$8;c=$13;print a,b,c}' terminal_output.txt`

This wont work if you have multiple `Success` lines before a `Completed` line etc.

Comment: This did not work.. I have exactly one ```Success``` line before a ```Completed``` line.. Any idea why this is not working? Also does ```awk``` modify the file itself? I see no changes whatsoever in the ```terminal_output.txt``` file and the output of the command did not echo anything to the screen